# Using assert for NaN in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I'm trying to use `assert.deepstrictEqual` to test that my output is `NaN`, as per the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepstrictequal_actual_expected_message). But the test won't pass

function code:

```
function howManyServings (params) {
  const {recipe, inventory} = params

  bread_confirm = Math.floor(inventory.bread / recipe.bread)
  peanutButter_confirm = Math.floor(inventory.peanutButter / recipe.peanutButter)
  jam_confirm = Math.floor(inventory.jam / recipe.jam)

  minimum_servings = Math.min(bread_confirm, peanutButter_confirm, jam_confirm)
  return minimum_servings
}
```

test code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const {howManyServings} = require('./index');
const inputs = require('./inputs')

describe('Nomnomthrough', () => {
  describe('When there is enough ingredient for one serving', () => {
    it('should return 1', () => {
      const output = howManyServings(inputs.oneServing);
      assert.equal(output, 1);
    });
  });
  describe('When there is enough for two servings', () => {
    it('should return 2', () => {
        const output = howManyServings(inputs.twoServings);
        assert.equal(output, 2)
    })
  })
  describe('When the amount is not an integer', () => {
    it('should return false', () => {
        const output = howManyServings(inputs.nonintegerValue);
        assert.deepStrictEqual(output, NaN)
    })
  })
});
```

input code:

```
module.exports = {
  oneServing: {
    recipe: {
      bread: 10,
      peanutButter: 5,
      jam: 5
    },
    inventory: {
      bread: 20,
      peanutButter: 10,
      jam: 5
    }
  },

  twoServings: {
    recipe: {
      bread: 10,
      peanutButter: 5,
      jam: 5
    },
    inventory: {
      bread: 20,
      peanutButter: 10,
      jam: 10
    }
  },

  nonintegerValue: {
    recipe: {
      bread: 10,
      peanutButter: 5,
      jam: 5
    },
    inventory: {
      bread: 20,
      peanutButter: 10,
      jam: 'sfsf'
    }
  }
}
```

The code returns `NaN` but it's not being recognized as equal to `NaN` which I thought `deepStrictEqual` would do.

Comment: `NaN` doesn't equal itself. Try `NaN === NaN` in the console.

Comment: Hmm then what's the point of the deepstrictEqual? Am I misunderstanding what it does?

Comment: I need to use tests

Comment: `isNaN()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Try: `assert.equal(isNaN(output), true)`

Comment: Judging by the name, `deepStrictEqual` recursively checks equality using the strict equality operator `===`. If that's the case, it will return `false` when comparing `NaN` values.

Comment: @palaѕн why not just `assert(isNaN(output))`?

Comment: @Mark_M yup, we can do it like that also or `assert.ok(isNaN(output))` also.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I know, I though that's what I was accomplishing in my code no? My output is NaN and I was using that assert function to pass it. I want that test to pass

Comment: @Amon no, you're misunderstanding `NaN`. NaN is the only value in JS that is not equal to itself. And I don't mean comparing two different objects/references that look alike. Try this `var value = NaN; console.log(value, value === value);` NaN is the only value in JS where this comparison will result as false; no references involved or anything, just comparing a primitive value against itself and it's returning false; and that by design.

Comment: @Thomas Okay, thanks, I knew that but stumbled upon deepstrictEqual and thought that may work

Comment: @palaѕн If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether the `output` variable is `NaN` you can use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) like:

```
assert(isNaN(output))
```

Or,

```
assert.equal(isNaN(output), true)
```

Or,

```
assert.ok(isNaN(output))
```

---

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

### Testing against `NaN`

`NaN` compares unequal (via `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==`) to any other value -- including to another NaN value. Use `Number.isNaN()` or `isNaN()` to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN. Or perform a self-comparison: NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself.

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true

function valueIsNaN(v) { return v !== v; }
valueIsNaN(1);          // false
valueIsNaN(NaN);        // true
valueIsNaN(Number.NaN); // true
```